# In Perl, an error occurred inside the inner eval{} can also be caught by the outer eval{}?

Tags: perl, eval

not so clear about this feature.

the situation is we have API which has its own eval catch, it returns normally a status. 
we use this API and need a specific status about the execution, the idea is to do an outer eval to catch if any error raised by the API. is it possible ? or it's ignored by the inside eval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the API "throws" an error with `die` when it "catches" an error, then yes, your outer `eval` can "catch" it and handle it as it wants.  If the API catches and just returns an error code as, say, a return value, then you don't need an outer `eval`.  A more specific example might help...

Answer (score 0):

Will work, checkout this example...

```
use strict;
use warnings;

eval { api_function(); };

if ($@) {
    warn "Oops! API error!";
}

sub api_function {

    eval {
        my $a = 1;

        my $x = 1 / $a;
    };

    if ($@) {
        warn "Oops! error!";
    }

    my $a = 0;

    my $x = 1 / $a;
}
```

Comment: Warning, do not try to catch errors using `eval` and `$@` directly unless you know exactly what you are doing (hint, if you aren't using `Try::Tiny` then you likely don't know what you are doing).  Always the use [`Try::Tiny`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Try-Tiny/lib/Try/Tiny.pm) to catch errors instead.  For more information on why, read the [background section of the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Try-Tiny/lib/Try/Tiny.pm#BACKGROUND).